# Flexbox exceeds its maincontainer in width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay, so i have a wrapper with 3 columns where the middle container is of a fixed width of 595px. The left and the right has a 2:1 size ratio. But when i put content into the left container which has width auto it exceeds the main wrappers width (width of screen 100%);

How do i solve this problem. I dont want it start grow like that i just want the colums to be responsive but width different width ratios.

If it helps, im in a angular project and i have a mat tab group inside the left column. I stil dont think this is the issue since it shouldnt exceed its main width

Here's the scass im using:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;


  & .column {
    margin: 5px;
    &.left {
      flex: 2;
      margin-left: 50px;

    }
    &.middle {
      min-width: 595px !important;
      max-width: 595px !important;
      flex:initial;
    }
    &.right {
      min-width: 350px !important; 
      flex: 1;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What size of screen are you looking at? Your content has a minimum width of, at least, 595 + 350 + 50 + 20 = 1115px, so, if the display you are looking at is smaller, it will overflow. You have given almost every element a minimum width.

Comment: I removed all widths and added flex:1; to every column, the left container gets very big and all three divs together exceeds the screens width, and a scrollbar appears..

Comment: Try adding `min-width: 0` to your flex items.

Comment: Could you add a snippet to your post where we can see this behavior? The problem maybe somewhere else, guessing what your HTML is like and using the CSS that you are telling us that you are using this problem does not happen. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raulsauco/6q3uebxj/4/).